# MVC - Best way to show and hide many controls in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controls

I have about 20 forms, each with 15-20 textbox inputs each.

Once the user submits the form, all their values need to be confirmed, this is done by replacing each textbox with a label control that shows the entered value.

The user may click on a back button to edit the data, in which case the textboxes re-appear, or they can confirm their data submission.

What would be the best way to handle this in MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend having different views for editing and showing data. This could be useful if you would like to omit or add some extra of the fields, keeping your view logic simple. You could store the form data in the database with some flag indicating that it is not confirmed yet. After confirmation you would only change the flag of the record. Another option is to store form data in tempData or Session and save it after confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would probably be to have both on the page and bound to the same Model properties but wrap them in some simple render logic. an example off the top of my head in razor could be something like

```
@if (is in edit state){
<field markup>
@}
else{@
<label markup>
@}
```

Its been a while since I've worked on an MVC app but that's how i would have done it back then i think.